# Creating new Parse user from input form

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am trying to create a new user for my Parse database, but it is not working with forms and inputs.
It only works if I hard code the value

```
<form>
  First Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" /> 
  <br><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" /> 
  <br><br>
  E-Mail: <input type="text" id="email" /> 
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="password" id="email" /> <br>
</form>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Sign Up" onclick="signUp();" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxx");

  function signUp() {

    var name = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", name);
    user.set("password", pass);
    user.set("email", mail);

  }
```

when setting the user instance variables, it works if I hard code the string as I said before, like this:

```
  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", "bob");
  user.set("password", 1234);
  user.set("email", "test@test.com");
```

I believe that something is going wrong when I call *getElementById().value* but I am not sure

Comment: did you check the developer console if there is any error

Comment: I forgot about that! thank you. It gave me an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`
When I tried to get the value of the password input

Comment: did you see that you have to change the id of password to password . you forgot to change it when copy and paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to change the ID of your password input:

```
E-Mail: <input type="text" id="email" /> 
<br><br>
Password: <input type="password" id="email" /> <br>
                                      ^
```

You probably meant to write

```
Password: <input type="password" id="password" /> <br>
```